# How to Change VL53L0X(TOF) sensor I2C address using c language on BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, c, beagleboneblack, source-code, i2c

Aim: To read Data from 4 VL53L0X(TOF) sensors using I2C communication in C language on BeagleBone Black Board (Debian OS).

I have implement c code for a single VL53L0X(TOF) sensor which is: *https://github.com/bitbank2/VL53L0X*

From the Above Link :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <tof.h> // time of flight sensor library
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int iDistance;
    int model, revision;

    // For Raspberry Pi's, the I2C channel is usually 1
    // For other boards (e.g. OrangePi) it's 0
    i = tofInit(2, 0x29, 1); // 2=I2CBus, 0x29 i2c slave address, 1 = long range.
    
    if (i != 1)
    {
        return -1; // problem - quit
    }
    printf("VL53L0X device successfully opened.\n");
    i = tofGetModel(&model, &revision);
    usleep(50000); // 50ms
    printf("Model ID =%d,\n", model);
    printf("Revision ID =%d,\n", revision);

    for (i=0; i<1200; i++) // read values 20 times a second for 1 minute
    {
        iDistance = tofReadDistance();
        if (iDistance < 4096) // valid range?
            printf("Distance = %dmm\n", iDistance);
        usleep(50000); // 50ms
    }

return 0;
} /* main() */
```

But My Application is to work with **4** VL53L0X(TOF) sensor.

Or another way to code in c to get the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have some code, it should be included in the question.  A link alone is insufficient.

Comment: given link is the source of code that I use. Thank you.

Comment: You need to [edit] the question so that it includes the code, not just the link.